# I altered my hostname, but every new vhost created, comes with the old hostname

Tags: dns, bind, virtualmin

I changed my hostname to `/etc/host` and `/etc/hostname`

I've rebooted the machine (vps) and checked in `virtualmin=>networking=>Hostname` and DNS Client and my new FQDN is already configured, I'm basing myself on a new domain that I bought for my new website to be the new FQDN name of my VPS : `vps5.newdomain.com` ... I have switched my PTR reverse with the new FQDN on my ISP (ovh and everything ok)

but every time I create a new virtual server, all settings in `virtualmin=>server configuration=>DNS Records` ( DNS Table )of this new domain added, comes with all the old settings! How do I update this within virtualmin and nginx and postfix(I have updated in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`)? virtualmin always did everything to me with the old domain `vps5.olddomain.com`, where I have to warn vitualmin that now my hostname is changed, is it a new hostname?

(I believe this is disrupting even in the generation of my dkim sign. because it is using as base a domain that no longer exists).

`ubuntu 16.04/64bits /nginx /mysql /webmin 1.860(last) /postfix /Bind9.10`

Thanks all/Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that you have also changed it here:

Webmin -> Networking -> Network Configuration -> Hostname and DNS Client, and you can change your hostname there.

Also Check

Virtualmin -> System Settings -> Server Templates -> Bind DNS Domain

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I resolved it a week ago by updating the data in the file: vim /etc/webmin/virtual-server/config bind_master but I'm very happy you tell me how to do via GUI! Thank you so much.

Comment: Virtualmin -> System Settings -> Server Templates -> Bind DNS Domain

Comment: Also Virtualmin -> Server Configuration -> Change Domain Name